# AS3 - if Statement not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

It's my second post here, and the first one as been quickly solved due to the knowledge of good member. So i would like to try one more time if you can help that will be wonderfull. It's for a Class project... And i'm getting stuck again...

Here is my code :

```
// TOP NAVIGATION - OVER ADDING CHILD //

var dest5:Number = -23; 
var home_button:mc_home1 = new mc_home1();
var globe_button:mc_globe1 = new mc_globe1();
var game_button:mc_game1 = new mc_game1();
var info_button:mc_info1 = new mc_info1();
var menudown_dest:Number = 58.9;
var menudown_dest_back:Number = -58.9;


function top_menu_bg(event:Event):void{
    if (dest5 != mc_top.y){
        var easeNum:Number = 0.93
        mc_top_bar.y = mc_top_bar.y * easeNum + dest5 * (1-easeNum);
    }
    if (mc_top_bar.y >= -23) {
    function top_menu_down(event:MouseEvent):void{
        if (menudown_dest != mc_top_bar.y)
        var easeNum:Number = 0.93
        mc_top_bar.y = mc_top_bar.y * easeNum + menudown_dest * (1-easeNum);
        }
        if (mc_top_bar.y >= 42.95)
        {
        addChild(home_button);
        home_button.x = 472.95;
        home_button.y = 39.15;
        addChild(globe_button);
        globe_button.x = 582.95;
        globe_button.y = 39.65;
        addChild(game_button);
        game_button.x = 699.95;
        game_button.y = 38.15;
        addChild(info_button);
        info_button.x = 812.95;
        info_button.y = 39.15;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, top_menu_bg);
    }
    mc_top_bar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, top_menu_down);
    }
    if (mc_top_bar.y >= 50.9) {
        function top_menu_bg_backup (event:MouseEvent):void{
            mc_top_bar.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, top_menu_down);
            if (menudown_dest_back != mc_top.y)
            var easeNum:Number = 0.93
            trace("hello1")
            mc_top_bar.y = mc_top_bar.y * easeNum + menudown_dest_back * (1-easeNum);
            }
            if (mc_top_bar.y >= 50)
                {
                removeChild(home_button);
                removeChild(globe_button);
                removeChild(game_button);
                removeChild(info_button);
                trace("hello2")
                }
            mc_top_bar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, top_menu_bg_backup);

            }
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, top_menu_bg);
```

So Everything works till the function top_menu_bg_backup, cause i'm tracing it... And not traceable ...

I'm trying to simplify my code as much as i can. It's my first time on a AS3 project. And still asking for the same project... Sorry

Comment: There indeed seems to be some curly bracket fails, and also you should probably keep all functions on the same level instead of nesting them like that. I tried to clean that up for a second but looks too messy, can't be sure which lines you ment to have in which function. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (menudown_dest_back != mc_top.y)
            var easeNum:Number = 0.93
```

This piece of code does not make too much sense. The variable declaration for easeNum will only exist on that line, and the value assigned to it will not be available anywhere else. Maybe you are missing a pair of curly braces?

Comment: Thanks for your Fast Reply.
Well the problem, isn't the Tween easeNum... but Maybe the {}... But i tried all ready and check it...
Might more be the fact that i remove the eventlistener... But can't figure out... Snif